# The inverse of the metric on the space of harmonic p-forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a manifold equipped with a riemannian metric $g$. The space of harmonic p-forms is an $b_{p}(X)$ dimensional vector space with $b_{p}(X)$, the pth Betti number. One can then define a metric tensor whose matrix elements are:

$$G^{(p)}_{AB} = \int_{X}\lambda_{A}\wedge \star_{g} \lambda_{B}$$

Here, the harmonic p-forms, $\{\lambda_A\}$ form a basis of the vector space of harmonic p-forms. They are dual to the independent p-cycles $\eta^{A} \in H_{p}(X)$, where $H_{p}(X)$ is the pth homology group. That is,

$$\int_{\eta^A}\lambda_{B} = \delta_{B}^{A}$$

I am interested in the inverse of the metric $G^{(p)}$. That is, I would like to find the matrix $G^{(p)-1}$. I believe that the inverse $G^{(p)^{-1}}$ is related to the intersection pairing between the independent cycles $\eta^A$, but I do not have sufficient knowledge in differential geometry to derive an explicit formula for the inverse metric. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want $X$ to be compact and oriented. Then $\star_g$ will realize Poincaré duality which is more or less what you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with Poincare duality, cup and cap products etc., but I am going to study this material from Hatcher. However, for the time being, I tried to approach this question by specializing to some specific cases, explicitly calculating the harmonic 1-forms dual to the two cycles on the 2-torus, then compute the matrix $G^{1}$. Also, If you can provide more detail so that I can prove this myself, it would be great

Comment: On a 2-torus $X= \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ with flat metric, the harmonic forms have constant coefficients. So a basis for the harmonic  $1$-forms consists of is $dx, dy$, and basis for $H_1(X)$ consists of the images of unit intervals along $x,y$ axes which is dual to the previous basis. So you should be work what you want in this case.